# How to increment manually semVer GitTools in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, auto-increment, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I use GitTools for auto increment semVer.

The current version: v1.1.1
calculate SemVer:
`"MajorMinorPatch": "1.2.0"`

**when incrementing the patch:**
`git commit -a -m "+semver: patch [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty`
`Write-Host "$(GitVersion.SemVer)"`
`print > "MajorMinorPatch": "1.2.0"`

**which I expect:**
`"MajorMinorPatch": "1.2.1"`

**more example**
when incrementing the minor:
`git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty`
`Write-Host "$(GitVersion.SemVer)"`
`print > "MajorMinorPatch": "1.2.0"`

which I expect:
`"MajorMinorPatch": "1.3.0"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the script: `git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty` before the `Execute GitVersion Task`.

Then the Git Tools task will update the version value. Otherwise, the execute task will not be able to read your commit information.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: gitversion/setup@0
  displayName: gitversion/setup
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x

- powershell: |
   
   git commit -a -m "+semver: minor [skip azurepipelines]" --allow-empty
   


- task: gitversion/execute@0
  displayName: gitversion/execute
  inputs:
    useConfigFile: true
    configFilePath: test.yml

- powershell: |
   
   Write-Host "$(GitVersion.SemVer)"
```

Comment: what's in test.yml?